# SQL Update from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a complete novice when it comes to SQL, just getting started.
I need help writing a query to update values in my SQL table:

Two tables:  Members, Chapters

Concerned with three columns in Chapters table: CHAP_NO, FA, FA2

i.e.

```
CHAP_NO     FA      FA2
111         1234567 2345689
222         2234567 4567899
333         3225545     
444                 
555         2358878 4566665
666         4568799
777         4566878 1233666
888         1119998     
999         3555879 6544799
```

etc. . .

Each value is a unique identifier

Concerned with two columns in Members table: MEMB_NO, CURR_CHAP

i.e.

```
MEMB_NO CURR_CHAP
1234567 665
5468787 664
4577789 122
4578767 233
7775666 588
4114748 787
```

etc. . .

Is it possible to automate an update based on if FA or FA2 is in Chapters table, update their CURR_CHAP value in the Members table from the CHAP_NO value?
From the above example data, I need MEMB_NO '1234567' to have his CURR_CHAP updated to '111' because he is listed as FA for CHAP_NO '111'

I really need to do this for similar MS SQL and MySQL databases if possible. If this can't be automated, I need help writing a query to manually update the Members table as exampled above with a 2 column manual update row of data:

```
MEMB_NO CURR_CHAP
5470011 547
5030038 545
3880188 544
1140753 543
4130019 543
5420011 542
5410010 541
2590511 540
4190109 540
4180296 539
5380020 538
5370012 537
1050859 536
4390125 535
4860144 535
5330009 533
5330061 533
1080746 532
2060321 531
1750750 529
4250135 528
8070013 528
1080645 527
5270053 527
2580695 526
2440073 525
2440163 525
5240010 524
4980035 523
2120380 522
4000418 521
3270185 520
4350210 519
4610218 518
5160004 516
1610450 515
5150065 515
5130046 513
5130050 513
5120047 512
1940306 510
2500170 510
5090087 509
5080014 508
1270803 505
1381026 505
2260505 504
3900106 504
5030006 503
1770526 501
1780355 501
5000017 500
4980037 498
2380411 497
4970019 497
4960044 496
4960127 496
4950012 495
4950095 495
1720409 494
2260867 494
2300466 493
3990055 492
4920204 492
1311252 491
2100252 491
1750592 490
1760563 490
2520403 489
4890051 489
4870076 487
4870143 487
4860153 486
1670856 485
4840054 484
4840143 484
2920024 483
4830136 483
1751087 482
1790828 481
1970128 481
2050815 480
4800027 480
1870246 478
3210174 478
4770100 477
4760124 476
4760126 476
1350640 475
2280722 475
2200077 474
3410230 474
4730100 473
4250159 470
4250156 470
3790179 464
4630164 463
4630139 463
2210062 461
4610188 461
4210110 460
4870065 459
4500246 450
1110937 449
1110934 449
2280501 447
4450323 445
4440114 444
4410135 441
4410216 441
1600799 435
2280449 435
4080089 431
4310132 431
1780525 427
4270190 427
4260502 426
4260550 426
4250467 425
4250485 425
4210328 421
4190230 419
4180005 418
4180341 418
4250232 417
4130004 413
4110444 411
4090133 409
4080308 408
4430119 408
4070279 407
4070443 407
1650354 405
1670725 404
2240204 402
2870319 400
3990114 399
3980014 398
4050073 398
3170399 397
3970348 397
1760487 395
4180191 395
1800443 394
2580288 394
1280499 393
3930227 393
3780058 391
3900377 390
2590362 389
1720492 385
1720398 384
2840325 383
3710142 381
3800235 380
3780407 378
1760459 375
1730026 373
3710306 371
3710228 371
1051294 370
3700332 370
3670174 367
1780583 359
4640038 359
1280614 358
2580373 358
3570449 357
3530560 353
3500046 350
3490275 349
3490244 349
3320203 348
3480310 348
4210188 346
3440364 344
4490223 344
1750642 342
3990257 342
1790541 341
3370562 337
3370738 337
1870336 334
3340382 334
1950674 333
1460619 328
3280586 328
4250013 326
1340705 324
2590495 324
2870029 322
3030290 322
1880232 321
2280415 321
3200547 320
3200568 320
3180132 318
3180178 318
3930433 317
4850072 317
2870449 315
3150168 315
1390763 313
3120170 312
3110048 311
3110110 311
3070267 307
3500231 306
3980122 306
1160708 305
3050510 305
2280197 304
3040348 304
1060785 303
1340760 303
3020534 302
3980151 301
2990239 299
1770425 297
2950573 295
2280513 294
2320434 287
2870594 287
4110133 284
4260131 278
2770221 277
2770366 277
2760484 276
2750397 275
2580694 272
1751006 267
4010252 267
2660235 266
2780335 265
2640326 264
3840125 263
1270872 259
2590690 259
2580728 258
2030556 257
4600151 257
2550390 255
4440010 255
2520461 252
4130095 252
3910117 250
2490314 249
1361032 247
1900370 247
2440211 244
2440101 244
1730150 243
1440258 242
2420062 242
1350511 238
2380559 238
1800598 237
2350417 235
2340372 234
2320453 232
2590582 232
2120104 230
2280696 228
3480122 227
1111011 226
2260626 226
3230234 222
2270200 221
4470101 221
3010326 219
2180334 218
2170591 217
1620648 213
2120524 212
3010424 212
3130060 210
2070261 207
2070313 207
1640858 206
1620684 205
2030573 203
2030810 203
1270589 201
1111015 200
1990448 199
1950384 195
1920328 192
1920684 192
1750798 188
1880607 188
1870445 187
1850587 185
2960295 185
1800721 180
1791166 179
3990116 178
3130119 177
4170034 177
1051172 176
1380942 176
1751011 175
4500021 175
2840346 174
3460307 174
1730027 173
4070275 173
1110986 171
1670586 167
1111222 166
2060385 164
1560459 163
1740135 162
3130093 161
1600695 160
1600682 160
1350600 159
1590341 159
1580464 158
1570742 157
1570761 157
4440077 156
1520404 152
4700010 152
3390033 147
4170240 145
4730144 143
4250191 142
1400502 140
2170212 140
1360713 139
3040299 139
1800519 136
1270930 135
1720638 134
1800462 133
3930387 133
1111000 131
1311274 131
1360547 128
2260776 128
4830091 127
1800431 123
1280523 122
1750851 122
1291052 121
3850165 121
1180219 118
1180477 118
2240110 116
2870263 116
3900143 114
1111488 111
1490386 111
1060765 110
1780463 110
3200394 108
5050015 108
3870219 105
```

Comment: you use both MySQL & MSSQL server ? weird

Comment: Source is MSSQL, migrating over to new MySQL, but still operate both until the transition is ready. MySQL is priority.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* this should work on both...

```
UPDATE 
    IGNORE Chapters,
    Members
SET Members.CURR_CHAP = Chapters.CHAP_NO
WHERE Chapters.FA = Members.MEMB_NO
AND Chapters.FA != ''
AND Chapters.FA2 != ''
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE members m 
INNER JOIN chapters c on (m.memb_no = c.fa or m.memb_no=c.fa2)
SET m.curr_chap=c.chap_no
```

Answer (score 0):

This query worked for me in MySql

```
update Members m
INNER JOIN chapters c
ON (m.memb_no=c.FA or m.memb_no=c.FA2)
set CURR_CHAP = c.CHAP_NO
```